# Installing rails on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner starting to learn Ruby on Rails and I would like to install rails on my Mac. I am following the instructions step-by-step on this website: http://installrails.com/steps/install_rails and when I type the command `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc`, I get the error below:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: Do you have the newest version of gem package manager installed? Try to run `gem update --system`.

Comment: 1. `gem update --system`. 2. `gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org`

Comment: I ran the command `gem update --system` but I get another error:
`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)`

Comment: [checkout this tut](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan)

Comment: Can you run `wget https://rubygems.org` sometimes due to internet connection, you are unable to connect via https://

Comment: Could you tell us what version of ruby and rubygems do you have installed? Type `ruby -v` and `gem -v` in the console

Comment: `ruby -v` outputs `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]` 

`gem -v` outputs `2.5.1` .

I think there's a problem with my gem in general cause when I try to download bundler by typing `gem install bundler`, I get the error below:

`ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)`

Comment: @IsmailM It's probably not internet connection, I typed `wget https://rubygems.org` and I get this response: `--2016-10-13 21:40:14--  https://rubygems.org/
Resolving rubygems.org... 151.101.128.70, 151.101.192.70, 151.101.0.70, ...
Connecting to rubygems.org|151.101.128.70|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                          [  <=>                                                 ]  11.18K  34.6KB/s    in 0.3s    

2016-10-13 21:40:14 (34.6 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [11445]`

Comment: Okay I have managed to solved my problem. It was about the internet proxy that I was using.

Comment: @JeffreyYong you should close the question

Comment: @AbhishekKumar What is the proper of closing the question?

Comment: @JeffreyYong This should help you => http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96283

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the internet proxy you are connecting to is right. It was just the problem of internet connection.